# Unable to navigate to Activity after successful login - Android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

**Issue**

After successful login verification from the server, unable to open New activity. Activity stays at Login Activity

**Background**

What I am trying to achieve here is open "Welcome" activity after successful User login. The server correctly validates the user login and displays the Toast, but not opening the activity

**Code**

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "<myURL>/login.php";

    public static final String KEY_LOGUSERNAME = "loUname";
    public static final String KEY_LOGPASSWORD = "loPass";

    EditText LogUser, LogPass;
    Button btnsLogin;

    String loUser, loPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initalizevars();
        btnsLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void initalizevars() {
        LogUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogUser);
        LogPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogPass);
        btnsLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    }

    private void login() {
        loUser = LogUser.getText().toString().trim();
        loPassword = LogPass.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.trim().equals("Success"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    openProfile();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_LOGUSERNAME, loUser);
                map.put(KEY_LOGPASSWORD, loPassword);
                return map;
            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);

    }

    private void openProfile() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnsLogin) {
            login();
        }

    }
```

The Toast is being displayed from the server response on successful verification

**What i tried**

I tried changing the Intent to below

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,Welcome.class);
startActivity(i);
```

But no luck.  Am stuck and unable to figure out where and what went wrong.

Requesting your help in putting me in the right direction.

Thanks

**EDIT**
i modified the if condition to be more meaningful and to debug as well

```
 if (response.trim().equals("Success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response + " Right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    openProfile();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response + " Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    openProfile();
                }
```

As suggested by user @user1232726, the else part is being considered and the activity is opened which should not be the case.

My login.php outputs

```
Success 
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script> 
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: it could b calling else part of the if statement. it should work

Comment: @user1232726 : Bingo Yes. Is working if i put the method in the else part. But why is it so? because i am verifying the success in the If condition and not the else. What am i missing here. Please let me know

Comment: Have you added the activity to manifest?

Comment: @user1232726 : Yes i have :)

Comment: Does your `toast` show `Success` when the login succeeds? Maybe the response string does not exactly match `Success`?

Comment: @IshitaSinha : It show Success and the same has been echoed in Server response as well (login. php) file . Strange is though when i have the method openProfile() in the else part (as suggested by @ user1232726 ), it takes me to that activity. Not sure whats wrong here and unable to figure our why

Comment: Could you do this and see what log is printed?

`public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(Login.class.getSimpleName(), response.trim());
                if(response.trim().equals("Success"))
                { ....`

Comment: Looks fine to me (assuming that the php works). You can try calling `finish()` after `startActivity`

Comment: @cricket_007 : No luck there :(

Comment: @IshitaSinha : This is the response `Success
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
`

Comment: Okay, then yeah, it obviously isn't working because your response is not exactly "Success"

Comment: @Sriram is this whole thing printed in the Log? or is it just the contents of your php file? If this whole thing _is_ printed in the log, then you need to check for this whole thing in your `if`.

Comment: @IshitaSinha : My Bad. The whole thing was printed in the log. I merely though it was some script passed from the free server am using. My Bad. I tried comparing the reponse using startswith. Its working. Thanks much.P.S. I am not sure how the javascript thing got added to my response. It was Success alone earlier.

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thanks :) I tried using startswith and it worked. Just to debug things. Not sure how the Javascript thing got added to the response.

Comment: Its probably added so the free hosting site can track the usage of its users and/or deliver ads. A better alternative to startsWith is to take the remove that section with a call to subString

Comment: @cricket_007 : Absolutely Agreed. :) Thanks much Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue was with the server response as it did return some javascript along with the success message. Guidance from @cricket_007, @IshitaSinha actually help me fix the issue.

Solution : Additional javascript/ or messages can be added When using free hosting sites. Check the entire response before comparing it with the actual response